# Position tablix elements at the same position on different pages in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have multiple tablixes that are rendered individually on each Excel worksheet when exported. However, I need the position of the tablixes to remain the same throughout all the different sheets, because currently, from the second sheet onwards, the tablix is not in the same position as the first one.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have done in the past:

1. You should create the tablix objects with a fixed height and width for better use of assignment.
2. You should be altering it more on the 'Properties' pane than trying to use the mouse for fixed positions to be more precise.  Set the 'tablix' object of my first one and select 'Size' to be 3in, 0.75in for 3 inch width and 0.75 in height.
3. I would set the 'Location' for the first to 0in,0in.  Then using a similar method as 2 for setting a fixed size, start you next one at 0in,(height of first)in.  So in my case it would be 0in,0.75in for the next one.
4. Set the 'PageBreak' > 'BreakLocation' to be 'End' for the first one and every other object you need to break onto a new page.  You should NOT do this for the last object as you could generate a blank final page potentially.

**Optional:**

You can name the pages as well that appear under 'PageName' as this names the sheet in Excel as well.

Comment: I have aligned the tablixes accordingly, but there still seem to be a couple of millimeters jump between the tablixes? Just a note that I cannot give a fixed width to the objects as the number of columns differ

Comment: Dude, I think I got it. So when I exported the report to Excel, there was a huge gap with regards to positioning between the tablixes. So, instead of putting the second tablix top position at 0,75 (height of tablix 1), I set it to 0 as well, so that the tablixes overlay eachother exactly. This resulted in exact positioning when exporting to Excel!

Comment: Cool, glad it worked for you.  Keep in mind for exact measurements in SSRS of columns, tablix, and other objects.  It tends to be easier to eyeball it and use the mouse and then when you are ready to publish set the widths and heights in the properties panel instead.

Comment: I followed your suggestion by using exact measurements in the Properties pane.

Answer (score 0):

Treat your report template as a Cartesian plane, with origin on top left corner with positive y-axis in the "down" direction. Ensure that your charts/graphs/tables are of the same dimension and placed at equidistant points within your plane. E.g. If you have two charts both 2 inches by 2 inches and your report template is 4 inches by 4 inches, then your first chart will be at (0,0) and your 2nd will be at (0,2). Keep this in mind and you will not falter, god-speed!